# Copy Builds to drop folder(UNC path) using visual studio online

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops

i am using the hosted build controller(visual studio online) for doing my builds. The problem is that i am not able to copy the build output to a UNC path(my dev server).

i know that we have to set the permissions(credentials), if it were to be a build server. But in this case since its visual studio online, how can we proceed ???

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I can be wrong but you cannot use an UNC path for a VSO build, the option is disabled. If you think this is pretty logical. You should have a network channel allowing SMB traffic from the Build Server in Azure (aka Hosted Build Controller, based on SASS model) to your File Share. You can go that route by installing TFS on Azure and configuring all the traffic and the IP routing (this is the IASS model).

What you can do is to set up your own build server (Controller + Agent) and register it with your VSO Collection.

If you just need to download the build outputs, navigate to the Build log page and you will find a button to get them ("Download drop as zip" or similar).

Comment: You do not need to make your internal build server accessible from VSO. All traffic is one way, from build server to VSO.

Comment: The option is not disabled. I can still copy the output to a UNC path. But here is the thing :

You can select to copy build output to a UNC path when build with hosted build controller. To make it works, you have to make sure the build service account can access the UNC path.

But when I initiate the build, I am doing it using my account. and my account has the access to the UNC path but it still gives me this error.
Exception Message: TF270016: An error occurred publishing log files from *******. Details: The network path was not found.


Any Ideas what can be done???